# Using templates with forward-declared types - safe?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, header, forward-declaration

I'm building an header-only library, and I've resolved some circular dependency issues by doing something similar to what the code shows.

Basically, I create a private template implementation that allows me to use forward-declared types as if they were included and not forward-declared.

**Is there anything dangerous about my approach?**

**Is there any performance loss?** *(the library's main focus is performance - the real code has explicit `inline` suggestions)*

Bonus question: **is there an impact (positive or negative) on compilation time?**

---

```
// Entity.h
#include "Component.h"
struct Entity { void a() { ... } }
```

---

```
// Component.h
struct Entity; // forward-declaration
class Component 
{        
    Entity& entity;
    template<class T = Entity> void doAImpl() { static_cast<T&>(entity).a(); } 

    public:
        // void notWorking() { entity.a(); } <- this does not compile
        void doA() { doAImpl(); }
}
```

Comment: I do something similar to this but I don't break the rules of what you can do with a forward declared type. As for "performance impact", there are none. I can't even tell why there would be any.

Comment: If your idea of "focus on performance" is "add `inline`", then I see a bleak future for that goal.

Comment: @delnan: I'm completely aware of the fact that `inline` is already implicit in header definitions. Also, I've gained about 5-8 frames per second by explicitly asking the compiler to inline some intensive parts of my libraries. *(libraries are part of a game engine)*

Comment: That's one thing, and it's great that you gained some FPS (though I still think this is an exception, and without more context, such as *absolute* numbers, FPS mean little - at 5000 FPS, 5 frames = 1 ms). But there are literally dozens of other things which influence performance (some of them more radically than inlining), such as the cache, aliasing, branches, late binding (`virtual`), and you mentioned *none* of these in favor of "I added `inline`" to underscore your performance focus. What I'm trying to say is, you may want to broaden your approaches to reasoning about performance.

Comment: @delnan: I know about all the things you mentioned. Maybe I was a little unclear in the question, but I mentioned adding `inline` not only to underscore my performance focus, but mostly to say: "I'm introducing a new function call by adding a template implementation - in my real code I use `inline` to maximize the chance of inlining the call to the templatized function, to avoid an extra function call. I didn't explicitly write it in the example code to save space."

Comment: Okay, then please excuse my zeal. Though I must wonder - if you know these things, shouldn't you also know that the most reliable way to settle performance doubts is to look at the assembly code and/or benchmark? ;-)

Comment: It seems to me that you can only use this construction sensibly if your call site includes `Entity.h` before calling `doA()`. If that's the case, then you might as well include the file directly. You can break circular dependencies by adding moving the function definition outside the class definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `Entity.h` is included in the call site, yeah. However if I include it in `Component.h`, the compiler complains, even if I move the implementations outside the definition. Do I need another header-file for the implementations?

Comment: whenever people start writing "game engine", common sense goes out the window for the sake of performance. Just focus on correctness and logical dependencies first. If you use `pimpl` for compilation speedup and template parameters to write abstract interfaces, there is usually little more room for compilation improvement.

Comment: I find it interesting that in the noise about performance the subject matter of the question seems to have gone missing: ***is it safe***? I address that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sufficient to declare `doA` in `Component.h`, and define it in `Entity.h`.

---

```
// Component.h

class Entity;

class Component
{
    void doA();
}
```

---

```
// Entity.h

class Entity { ... }

// still in Entity.h
void Component::doA() { entity.a(); }
```

Comment: I like this because it solves the problem with the minimum fuss. Having said that, it's rather confusing to anyone trying to read the code - it being somewhat unconventional to have the body of a member definition declared in the `Component` module be defined in the `Entity` module. Not *wrong* per se, just likely to be banned by most coding standards.

Comment: @willj: Do you think it would be worth adding another header file for the implementation?

Comment: It sounds like there is a circular dependency between the modules `Entity` and `Component`. I would recommend asking a new question - including full details of the reason for the circular dependency - and asking for suggestions how to refactor it.

Answer (score 3):

> **Is there anything dangerous about my approach?**

As long as the template instantiation is, in fact, deferred, not much can go wrong. It could maybe declare intent a bit better if you prohibited an incorrect instantiation:

```
typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< T, Entity >::value
    && sizeof ( T ) /* Ensure that Entity is not incomplete. */ >::type
```

On second reading of your code, it looks like the non-template `doA` function will immediately and prematurely instantiate `doAImpl`, defeating the templating. I don't think the public interface can be a non-template, since it must cause instantiation of whatever `Impl` ultimately does the work, but only when the function is actually used. Unless there's another layer of templating protecting the user, it's probably better to do away with the `private` part and do everything in `doA`.

> **Is there any performance loss?**

Nope. The function is sure to be inlined either way.

> **Is there an impact (positive or negative) on compilation time?**

The minuscule added complexity will certainly not make a difference.

---

The only reason not to do this is obvious: it's ugly. And quite likely a violation of separation of concerns.

One workaround would be to use a non-member, free function instead.

```
struct Entity;
void a( Entity & );

    void doA() { a( entity ); }
```

Another would be to simply treat `Entity.h` or whatever as a dependency and include it. I think this would be the most popular solution.

If `Component` is really not dependent on `Entity`, then maybe `doA` belongs in a derived class which should have its own new header, which includes both the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the header `Component.h` will fail to compile unless you also `#include Entity.h`. This will result in mysterious errors in `Component.h` if you were ever to try to `#include Component.h` separately; to change `Entity.h` so that it does not contain a complete definition of `Entity`; or to change `Library.h` so that it no longer contains `#include Entity.h`. This is generally considered bad practice as this error would be difficult to understand for a future maintainer of the code.

clang gives `error: member access into incomplete type 'Entity'`

Here's a live example demonstrating the error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d6737c6f710992cce8a3f28217562da2-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336

The function `doAImpl()` is instantiated if it is called in a context that does not depend on a template parameter. At the point of instantiation, `Entity` is used in a class-member-access and therefore required to be complete. If you do not `#include Entity.h`, the type `Entity` will not be complete at the point of instantiation.

A much simpler (and prettier) way to achieve what you want is to do:

```
template<class Entity>
class Component 
{        
    Entity& entity;

    public:
        void doA() { entity.a(); } // this compiles fine
};
```

In general, (even in a header-only library) you can avoid a lot of headaches by following this simple rule: every header `name.h` must have a matching `name.cpp` which contains `#include name.h` before any other `#include` directive. This guarantees that `name.h` can be safely included anywhere without resulting in this kind of error.

This is the canonical reference, from John Lakos in *Large-Scale C++ Software Design*, quoted by Bruce Eckel in *Thinking in C++*: http://bruce-eckel.developpez.com/livres/cpp/ticpp/v1/?page=page_18

> Latent usage errors can be avoided by ensuring that the .h file of a component parses by itself - without externally-provided declarations or definitions... Including the .h file as the very first line of the .c file ensures that no critical piece of information intrinsic to the physical interface of the component is missing from the .h file (or, if there is, that you will find out about it as soon as you try to compile the .c file).

Comment: It compiles with both `clang++ 3.4` and `g++ 4.8.1`. As mentioned in one of the comments in the question, the requirement for this to work is having the call site include `Entity.h`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You might want to double check that.

Comment: I'm sure it works. My library is composed of `Component.h`, `Entity.h` and `Manager.h`. It also has a `LIBRARY.h` main include which is intended to be included in external projects. `LIBRARY.h` does nothing but include `Component.h`, `Entity.h` and `Manager.h`. In an external projects, when I write `#include <LIBRARY.h>`, I can then use `Component::doA()` without any compiler error. I guess the compiler error occurs in your example because you're trying to use `Component::doA()` in the library itself.

Comment: If you always `#include Entity.h` before `#include Component.h`, what exactly is the point of forward-declaring `Entity` in `Component.h` ?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to compile without forward-declarations. The classes are very closely related to each other. Though, now that you mention it, it doesn't seem very logical that it doesn't compile without forward-declaration.

[The library is here, if you want to take a closer look.](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVEntitySystem)

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo, I don't think you get what Willj said. Willj said "component.h" can not be compiled "standalone". Yes you can compile your cpp file which include "entity.h". But you can not compile the header "Component.h" standalone

Comment: Note that (to me, surprisingly) using a forward-decl and a definition of `Entity` *after* the definition of `Component` makes the OP's code [compile fine on Coliru's clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d19aa9579545d8a54ab5f1fae3d8030b-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852). I'll have to look up the name lookup for this case, as I thought the instantiation context would be inside `Component::doA`, which wouldn't find `Entity::a`.

Comment: Yes, it's a special rule I guess: [temp.point]/7 "A specialization for a [...] member function template [...] may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, **and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation.**"

Comment: As headers (or their non-StdLib equivalent) are not compiled "standalone", but only when they're included in source files, you might want to solve this ambiguity in your first sentence.

Comment: The first paragraph isn't strictly true. It will fail *if* the function is called without the extra header, but how would the user use the result without that header, anyway? The interface isn't dangerous in this sense because it works as long as it could do something useful.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the danger is that the failure may occur unexpectedly at some future time, and will then be difficult to understand for whoever encounters it.

Comment: @willj Failure will occur only when they access that particular function. Whether the function is clearly specified/documented to require the other header is a valid concern, but the unexpectedness goes no further than that.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: failure will occur if they include `Component.h` on its own, regardless of whether they call that particular function.

Comment: @willj Because the member access expression involving `a` only occurs with a template argument dependent type, the name `a` is only resolved upon template instantiation. That is the purpose of his exercise. On second thought, he is instantiating the template immediately in `doA`, which will fail. His actual use case probably differs but I should note this in my answer…

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put implementation in "*.inl"

// Entity.h

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H

class Component; // forward-declaration
struct Entity { void a(); };

#include "Entity.inl" 

#endif
```

// Entity.inl

```
#ifndef ENTITY_INL
#define ENTITY_INL

#include "Component.h";
inline void Entity::a() { /* implementation using Component and Entity */}

#endif
```

// Component.h

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_H
#define COMPONENT_H

struct Entity; // forward-declaration
class Component 
{        
    Entity& entity;
    public:
        void doA();
};

#include "Component.inl"

#endif
```

// Component.inl

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_INL
#define COMPONENT_INL

#include "Entity.h";
inline void Component::doA() { entity.a(); }

#endif
```

Comment: This looks like a nicer solution. I'll try it out

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to avoid creating the new `.inl` files though - I kinda liked having everything in a single header file.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: You could put the definitions for `Entity` and `Component` into a single file rather than in three files if you prefer...

Comment: this will not work: `Entity::a()` is defined after it is first called in "Component.inl"

Comment: Since "file.inl" is only included by its corresponding "file.h", you may copy/paste "file.inl" content in place of '#include "file.inl"' (**keeping** the included guards).

Comment: @TemplateRex: we have declaration of both Component/Entity before any function definition. So it is ok.

Comment: but now you have "Entity.h" includes "Entity.inl" includes "Component.h" includes "Component.inl" includes "Entity.h" so a cyclic dependency

Comment: I specified that I omitted to show include Guard (#ifndef FILE_H #define FILE_H ... #endif), and my "cycle" is Entity.h -> 'Entity declaration' -> Entity.inl -> Component.h -> 'Component declaration' -> Component.inl -> (Skipped Entity.h) 'Component definition', 'Entity definition'.

Comment: +1 I suggest you include the *include guards* and demonstrate the file inclusion tree in your answer as you did in the comment.

Comment: I'm a bit mystified as to how this "suggestion" will answer the OP's question.

Comment: @sehe: my suggestion fixes the circular dependency, and so the question of OP is unneeded.

Comment: Hmmm. Still doesn't _answer_ it, right. (Also, the question in itself has a value and I don't think that is invalidated by there a possible workaround for any particular case.)

Comment: @Jarod42  include guards are not meant to solve circular dependencies issues, they are meant to prevent multiple inclusions, which is quite different.